# Zend Framework 2 Theme Manager

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

have on question about the Zend Framework 2.
In my Application i have a module whiche handles my whole Application.

For further improvements i want to develop a Theme Manager.

The Theme Manager should work with url params like ?theme = lightTheme.
The Themes are organized in a Folder "templates" somewehere outside the Module.
The Themes should also include the view scripts.

As far as i know from reading some ZF2 documentations it could be achieved with some Listener Events.

Does anybody did that alright or can give me some example how ich can solve this requirement ?

Comment: I've heard this as well about the Listener Events. What they mean is that in your Module.php class you register an event with the application. Then, you change the layout file depending on some condition. Of course, each layout file is a 'theme' that will use diff CSS files. I'll try to put up a link to the webpage that I saw this on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this pattern could work...

**themes folder structure**

```
/path/to/themes
/path/to/themes/some_theme
/path/to/themes/some_theme/layout.phtml
/path/to/themes/another_theme
/path/to/themes/another_theme/layout.phtml
```

**config/module.config.php**

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            '/path/to/themes',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Module.php**

```
namespace Something;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e)
    {
        $application = $e->getApplication();
        $em = $application->getEventManager();
        $em->attach('route', function($e) {

            // decide which theme to use by get parameter
            // $layout = 'some_theme/layout';
            // $layout = 'another_theme/layout';
            $e->getViewModel()->setTemplate($layout);
        });
    }
}
```

// edit: changed to use the route event instead of controllerLoader